# Github contributions not showing up on profile graph?

Tags: github

I have done my research and tried to diagnose the issue myself, but cannot find the answer. I have been contributing on a consistent basis to a repo for the company that I work for and I don't see any of my contributions and I have all my settings set to display public and private contributions.

The only thing I can think of is, since I am creating separate branches and  then not merging the branch to master the reason behind my contributions not showing up on my profile? Only on the branch of the repo itself are my contributions being shown when I view the repo on github.

It would be very much appreciated if I could get a thorough understanding of this as I am very confused.

Comment: That's not a programming question. Have you contacted the service provider (i.e. github)?

Comment: Yes, I've heard nothing back. (it's been weeks)

Comment: Is this solved?

Comment: Yes, thank you for following up!

Comment: Oops, must have missed the notification for this comment..Do you mind using the checkmark to mark it as solved then (and perhaps going through your asked questions and seeing which of those can be marked solved? :P. Otherwise these questions stay kicking around the "Unanswered" category in eternal purgatory).

Answer (score 0):

Commits to branches other than `master` (or whatever your default branch is named) do not appear on the contribution graph until the branch is merged.

See: [Contributions That Are Counted](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile/#contributions-that-are-counted)

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, was originally under a commit email address from past employment. Used `git config --global user.email "email@mail.com"` to resolve the issue.